# What is the best way to git patch a subrange of a branch?

Tags: git

In Subversion, it is easy to merge a range of changesets/diffs from a branch using "svn merge -r a:b mybranch". But in git, I found it is only possible to cherry-pick a single commit from a branch to apply that patch to my current working branch. So I am wondering if there is a fast way to apply all the commits in one swoop between two tags in a bugfix branch to my current master branch?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The easiest way to perform the action that you are looking for is with `git rebase`. Here's a recipe. Assume that tag A is the commit on top of which the patch series that you want to select is based and that tag B is the commit of the final patch in the series. Also, assume that br is the name of the current branch and the branch where the new patch series should be applied.

```
# Checkout a new temporary branch at the current location
git checkout -b tmp

# Move the br branch to the head of the new patchset
git branch -f br B

# Rebase the patchset onto tmp, the old location of br
git rebase --onto tmp A br
```

Comment: It should be noted that you can't retain information about the origin of those commits this way.

Comment: I needed this exact functionality about five times in the past three days. So much better than cherry picking each commit.

Comment: Excellent.  This is the useful kind of "move a whole set of commits in a really weird way" effect that I needed.

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify 'cause I didn't get it, the tag A is actually the commit -right-before- the first one in the series you want to include.  So tag A won't be included, only the tags after.

Comment: Just used this trick; did a very complex merge that WOULD NOT BE POSSIBLE in most other VCS s, in 30 minutes.!!!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I've found to do this is:

```
git cherry-pick starthash..endhash
```

Note that the two dots have no spaces separating them from the hash labels. Also, this will not cherry-pick `starthash`, but rather everything after `starthash` up to and including `endhash`. To include `starthash` do `git cherry-pick starthash^..endhash`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can't *git merge* this way. Merge is intended to join two branches which have a history in common, not for picking up several commits or patch series. I feel like cherry-picking is fundamentally what you're asking for.

You can use *git cherry* (not *cherry-pick*!) to find out which commits should be inserted into your branch, then *git cherry-pick* them. You can also explicitly ask *git cherry-pick* to record the origin of those commits in case you're cherry-picking from a public branch. This is probably the best way to deal with this problem. (Another could have been to export them via *git format-patch* and then importing them with git-am/git-apply, but that would likely be slower, plus it won't record the origin of the commits.)

EDIT: "Public" (branch) should be understood as something not subject to history editing. Of course, you can do this when developing closed-source software without the code being public.