# How to cherry-pick a range of commits and merge them into another branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I have the following repository layout:

- master branch (production)
- integration
- working

What I want to achieve is to cherry-pick a range of commits from the working branch and merge it into the integration branch. I'm pretty new to git and I can't figure out how to exactly do this (the cherry-picking of commit ranges in one operation, not the merging) without messing the repository up. Any pointers or thoughts on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1053, accepted):

When it comes to a range of commits, cherry-picking <del>is</del> *was* impractical.

As [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664543/6309) by [Keith Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442025/keith-kim), Git 1.7.2+ introduced the ability to cherry-pick a range of commits (but you still need to be aware of the [consequence of cherry-picking for future merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112))

> git cherry-pick" learned to pick a range of commits
> (e.g. "`cherry-pick A..B`" and "`cherry-pick --stdin`"), so did "`git revert`"; these do not support the nicer sequencing control "`rebase [-i]`" has, though.

[damian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42961/damian) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/6309) and warns us:

> In the "`cherry-pick A..B`" form, **`A` should be older than `B`**.
> **If they're the wrong order, the command will silently fail**.

If you want to pick the **range `B` through `D` (including `B`)** that would be **`B~..D`** (instead of `B..D`).
See "[Git create branch from range of previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853814/6309)" for an illustration.

As [Jubobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jubobs) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#comment51629396_1994491):

> This assumes that `B` is not a root commit; you'll get an "`unknown revision`" error otherwise.

Note: as of Git 2.9.x/2.10 (Q3 2016), you can cherry-pick a range of commits directly on an orphan branch (empty head): see "[How to make an existing branch an orphan in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285663/6309)".

---

Original answer (January 2010)

A `rebase --onto` would be better, where you replay the given range of commits on top of your integration branch, as [Charles Bailey described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509859/what-is-the-best-way-to-git-patch-a-subrange-of-a-branch).
(also, look for "Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another" in the [git rebase man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), to see a practical example of `git rebase --onto`)

If your current branch is integration:

```sh
# Checkout a new temporary branch at the current location
git checkout -b tmp

# Move the integration branch to the head of the new patchset
git branch -f integration last_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range

# Rebase the patchset onto tmp, the old location of integration
git rebase --onto tmp first_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range~1 integration
```

That will replay everything between:

- after the parent of `first_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range` (hence the `~1`): the first commit you want to replay
- up to "`integration`" (which points to the last commit you intend to replay, from the `working` branch)

to "`tmp`" (which points to where `integration` was pointing before)

If there is any conflict when one of those commits is replayed:

- either solve it and run "`git rebase --continue`".
- or skip this patch, and instead run "`git rebase --skip`"
- or cancel the all thing with a "`git rebase --abort`" (and put back the `integration` branch on the `tmp` branch)

After that `rebase --onto`, `integration` will be back at the last commit of the integration branch (that is "`tmp`" branch + all the replayed commits)

With cherry-picking or `rebase --onto`, do not forget it has consequences on subsequent merges, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112).

---

A pure "`cherry-pick`" solution is [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-version-control/F0KYheOR2dY/pLj70x0A8L0J), and would involve something like:

> If you want to use a patch approach then "git format-patch|git am" and "git cherry" are your options.
> Currently, `git cherry-pick` accepts only a single commit, but if you want to pick the range `B` through `D` that would be `B^..D` (actually `B~..D`, see below) in Git lingo, so:

```sh
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order B~..D | while read rev 
do 
  git cherry-pick $rev || break 
done
```

But anyway, when you need to "replay" a range of commits, the word "replay" should push you to use the "`rebase`" feature of Git.

---

[pridmorej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269458/pridmorej) objects in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-them-into-another-branch/1994491?noredirect=1#comment136776954_1994491):

> WARNING: don't be fooled by the above suggestion of using carat (`^`) to make the range inclusive!
>
> This does not include `CommitId1` if, for instance, the parent of `CommitId1` is a merge commit:`git cherry-pick CommitId1^..CommitId99`.
> In that case, `cherry-pick` still starts from `CommitId2` - no idea why, but that's the behavior I've experienced.
>
> I did, however, discover that using tilde (`~`) works as expected, even when the parent of `CommitId1` is a merge commit: `git cherry-pick CommitId1~..CommitId99`.

True: that highlights an important nuance in using Git's cherry-picking command with commit ranges, particularly when dealing with merge commits.

In Git, `^` and `~` have specific meanings when used with commit references:

- `^` refers to the parent of a commit, and when used in a range, it can lead to unexpected results, especially with merge commits.
- `~`, on the other hand, is used to denote the first parent of a commit in a linear history, which makes it more predictable in the context of cherry-picking a range.

When cherry-picking a range of commits, especially in scenarios involving merge commits, prefer using `~` to make sure the range includes the intended commits.

So regarding `git cherry-pick CommitId1^..CommitId99`: When specifying a range `CommitId1^..CommitId99`, Git interprets this as "start from the parent of `CommitId1` and include commits up to `CommitId99`".

- If `CommitId1` is a regular commit, its only parent (say `CommitId0`) becomes the start of the range, effectively excluding `CommitId1` itself.
- If `CommitId1` is a merge commit, `CommitId1^` still points to its first parent. That can be particularly confusing because merge commits by their nature merge two lines of development, and the first parent might not be intuitively the "previous" commit in a linear sense.

In non-linear histories involving merge commits, the first parent of a merge commit might not be the direct predecessor in the *same* branch.

The tilde (`~`) notation, when used as in `CommitId1~..CommitId99`, effectively means "include `CommitId1` and go back one commit from there", which in most cases will include `CommitId1` in the range, as intended.

Consider the following commit history, where `M` represents a merge commit, and each letter represents a different commit:

```sh
A---B---C-------D---E--CommitId99   <- master
     \         /
      X---Y---M                     <- feature (CommitId1 is M)
```

- `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` are commits on the `master` branch.
- `X`, `Y` are commits on a `feature` branch.
- `M` is a merge commit on the `feature` branch, merging changes from `master` into `feature`. Here, `M` is `CommitId1`.

When you run the command:

```sh
git cherry-pick CommitId1^..CommitId99
```

- `CommitId1` is `M`.
- `CommitId1^` refers to the first parent of `M`.
- In this case, the first parent of `M` is `D` because merge commits list their parents in the order they were merged.

So, the range `CommitId1^..CommitId99` translates to `D..CommitId99`. M (`CommitId1`) is excluded!

But if you use  `git cherry-pick CommitId1~..CommitId99`, when used in the context of a range, like `CommitId1~..CommitId99`, the interpretation is "start from the commit right before `CommitId1` and include up to `CommitId99`."

So `CommitId1~` refers to the commit right before `M` in the `feature` branch, which is `Y` (since `M` was created on the `feature` branch, by a merge from `master` to `feature`).
The range `CommitId1~..CommitId99` translates to `Y..CommitId99`.

Using `~` in the range with `git cherry-pick` effectively shifts the start of the range to the commit right before `CommitId1`, thereby including `CommitId1` in the cherry-picked range. That behavior is particularly useful when you want to include merge commits in your cherry-picking operation.

Comment: If you have commits that have parents that require the `-m` option, how do you handle those commits? Or is there a way to filter out these commits?

Comment: @aug `-m` is supposed to handle them for you, by selecting the mainline referenced by the `-m` parameter you have chosen for this cherry-picking.

Comment: The thing is if you are cherry picking a range of commits, it will cherry pick the parent commits correctly but then when it hits a normal commit, it fails and says commit is not a merge. I guess my question is better phrased how to make it pass the `-m` option only when it hits a parent commit when cherry-picking range of commits? Right now if I pass `-m` like `git cherry-pick a87afaaf..asfa789 -m 1` it applies to all commits within the range.

Comment: @aug Strange, I did not reproduce the issue. What is your git version and whayt is the exact error message you see?

Comment: Ah I'm running git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63). The error I see would be something like `error: Commit 8fcaf3b61823c14674c841ea88c6067dfda3af48 is a merge but no -m option was given.` I actually realized you could just `git cherry-pick --continue` and it would be fine (but it wouldn't include the parent commit)

Comment: i just cherry-picked a range and it's not the same as individually applying cherry-pick to each commit..ran into weird conflict errors

Comment: @dtc Strange: maybe you could ask a new question with more details (git version, OS, git config -l, ...), to see if that behavior is expected or not?

Comment: The way I understand it is this. If you want to *move* commits, you need to `rebase`. If you want to *copy* commits (leaving the original branch alone), you should use `cherry-pick`. I find that a cherry-pick followed by an interactive rebase is great for cleaning up work. Does that follow with everyone else's thinking?

Comment: @jocull I don't see often a cherry-pick + rebase -i, but yes, that should work.

Comment: Don't remember from which version, but `git cherry-pick -<NUMBER_OF_COMMITS> <HASH_OF_LAST_COMMIT>` works like a charm!

Comment: Is `git branch -f integration last_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range` necessary? Can't you just use the SHA-1's directly in the rebase command? `git rebase --onto tmp first_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range~1 last_SHA-1_of_working_branch_range`

Comment: Update: This isn't possible since you'll be on a detached HEAD after.

Comment: @ClementHoang True: a rebase starts by switching to (git switch, no more checkout since Git 2.23: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) the new upstream branch. If said upstream branch is not a branch but a SHA1...: detached HEAD.

Comment: May you never have to itch again and may your eyes only see bushy-tailed rabbits. Thank you!

Comment: WARNING: don't be fooled by the above suggestion of using carat (^) to make the range inclusive!

This does not include CommitId1 if, for instance, the parent of CommitId1 is a merge commit.  

`git cherry-pick CommitId1^..CommitId99`

In that case cherry-pick still starts from CommitId2 - no idea why, but that's the behaviour I've experienced.

I did, however, discover that using tilde (~) works as expected, even when the parent of CommitId1 is a merge commit:

`git cherry-pick CommitId1~..CommitId99`

Comment: @pridmorej Excellent point, thank you! I have edited the answer accordingly, and I have added a study to explain and illustrate why `~` is better than `^` when cherry-picking a range of commits. Please let me know if that study makes sense for you.

Answer (score 170):

As of git v1.7.2 cherry pick can accept a range of commits:

> `git cherry-pick` learned to pick a range of commits (e.g. `cherry-pick A..B` and `cherry-pick --stdin`), so did `git revert`; these do not support the nicer sequencing control `rebase [-i]` has, though.

As [Gabe Moothart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13356/gabe-moothart) notes, `cherry-pick A..B` will not get commit `A` (you would need `A~1..B` for that), and if there are any conflicts git will not automatically continue like rebase does (at least as of 1.7.3.1).

Answer (score 117):

Assume that you have 2 branches,

"branchA" : includes commits you want to copy (from "commitA" to "commitB"

"branchB" : the branch you want the commits to be transferred from "branchA"

1)

```
 git checkout <branchA>
```

2) get the IDs of "commitA" and "commitB"

3)

```
git checkout <branchB>
```

4)

```
git cherry-pick <commitA>^..<commitB>
```

5) In case you have a conflict, solve it and type

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

to continue the cherry-pick process.

Comment: What does the "^" do in the "git cherry-pick <commitA>^..<commitB>" command at 4)?

Comment: @JVM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: Someone please edit the post that the `cherry-pick` range is NOT inclusive.

Comment: @JVM when you use cherry-pick without the `^` in the range, the first commit will not be included

Comment: @JVM `^` indicates the previous commit. As @Tomas pointed, `cherry-pick`'s behavior leaves the commitA. So to include `commitA`, you need to choose the respective previous commit using `commitA^`

Comment: For anyone else that isn't aware, if you're using zsh, you need to surround your range in quotes: `git cherry-pick "<commitA>^..<commitB>"`

Comment: @DrewDaniels I wonder the side effect of quoting the hash range on a non zsh system.

Answer (score 37):

Are you sure you don't want to actually merge the branches? If the working branch has some recent commits you don't want, you can just create a new branch with a HEAD at the point you want.

Now, if you really do want to cherry-pick a range of commits, for whatever reason, an elegant way to do this is to just pull of a patchset and apply it to your new integration branch:

```
git format-patch A..B
git checkout integration
git am *.patch
```

This is essentially what git-rebase is doing anyway, but without the need to play games. You can add `--3way` to `git-am` if you need to merge. Make sure there are no other *.patch files already in the directory where you do this, if you follow the instructions verbatim...

Comment: Note that, same as with other revision ranges, it needs to be `A^` to include `A`.

Answer (score 27):

### git cherry-pick *start_commit_sha_id*^..*end_commit_sha_id*

e.g. `git cherry-pick 3a7322ac^..7d7c123c`

**Assuming** you are on `branchA` where you want to pick commits (*start & end commit SHA for the range is given and left commit SHA is older*) from `branchB`. The entire range of commits (both inclusive) will be cherry picked in `branchA`.

The [examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples) given in the official documentation are quite useful.

Answer (score 9):

I wrapped [VonC's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491) into a short bash script, `git-multi-cherry-pick`, for easy running:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Equivalent to running git-cherry-pick on each of the commits in the range specified.";
    echo "";
    echo "Usage:  $0 start^..end";
    echo "";
    exit 1;
fi

git rev-list --reverse --topo-order $1 | while read rev 
do 
  git cherry-pick $rev || break 
done
```

I'm currently using this as I rebuild the history of a project that had both 3rd-party code and customizations mixed together in the same svn trunk. I'm now splitting apart core 3rd party code, 3rd party modules, and customizations onto their own git branches for better understanding of customizations going forward. `git-cherry-pick` is helpful in this situation since I have two trees in the same repository, but without a shared ancestor.

Answer (score 8):

`git cherry-pick FIRST^..LAST` works only for simple scenarios.

To achieve a decent "merge it into the integration branch" while having the usal comfort with things like auto-skipping of already integrated picks, transplanting diamond-merges, interactive control ...) better use a rebase. One answer here pointed to that, however the protocol included a dicey `git branch -f` and a juggling with a temp branch. Here a straight robust method:

```
git rebase -i FIRST LAST~0 --onto integration
git rebase @ integration
```

The `-i` allows for interactive control.
The `~0` ensures a detached rebase (not moving the / another branch) in case LAST is a branch name. It can be omitted otherwise. The second rebase command just moves the `integration` branch ref in safe manner forward to the intermediate detached head - it doesn't introduce new commits. To rebase a complex structure with merge diamonds etc. consider `--rebase-merges` or  `--rebase-merges=rebase-cousins` in the first rebase.

Answer (score 6):

I have tested that some days ago, after reading the  very clear explanation of Vonc.

## My steps

### Start

- Branch `dev` : A B C D E F G H I J
- Branch `target`: A B C D
- I don't want `E` nor `H`

### Steps to copy features without the step E and H in the branch `dev_feature_wo_E_H`

- `git checkout dev`
- `git checkout -b dev_feature_wo_E_H`
- `git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges --no-ff D` where I put `drop` front of `E` and `H` in the rebase editor
- resolve conflicts, continue and `commit`

### Steps to copy the branch `dev_feature_wo_E_H` on target.

- `git checkout target`
- `git merge --no-ff --no-commit  dev_feature_wo_E_H`
- resolve conflicts, continue and `commit`

## Some remarks

- I've done that because of too much `cherry-pick` in the days before
- `git cherry-pick` is powerful and simple but

  - it creates duplicates commits
  - and when I want to `merge` I have to resolve conflicts of the initial commits and duplicates commits, so for one or two `cherry-pick`, it's OK to "cherry-picking" but for more  it's too verbose and the branch will become too complex

Comment: The moment you remove E F from the branch, you're rewritting (creating duplicates) of G H I J. It's no different than cherry picking them as individual commits.

Comment: For me cherry-pick should be an exception: merge is more in the original concept of git.

Comment: My point is that rebase resembles more cherry-pick than merge.
But I think I get your point now, you want to see the merge in the target branch (no-ff) rather than just plain cherry-picking.

Answer (score 3):

All the above options will prompt you to resolve merge conflicts. If you are merging changes committed for a team, it is difficult to get resolved the merge conflicts from developers and proceed. However, "git merge" will do the merge in one shot but you can not pass a range of revisions as argument. we have to use "git diff" and "git apply" commands to do the merge range of revs. I have observed that "git apply" will fail if the patch file has diff for too many file, so we have to create a patch per file and then apply. Note that the script will not be able to delete the files that are deleted in source branch. This is a rare case, you can manually delete such files from target branch. The exit status of "git apply" is not zero if it is not able to apply the patch, however if you use -3way option it will fall back to 3 way merge and you don't have to worry about this failure.

Below is the script.

```
enter code here



  #!/bin/bash

    # This script will merge the diff between two git revisions to checked out branch
    # Make sure to cd to git source area and checkout the target branch
    # Make sure that checked out branch is clean run "git reset --hard HEAD"


    START=$1
    END=$2

    echo Start version: $START
    echo End version: $END

    mkdir -p ~/temp
    echo > /tmp/status
    #get files
    git --no-pager  diff  --name-only ${START}..${END} > ~/temp/files
    echo > ~/temp/error.log
    # merge every file
    for file in `cat  ~/temp/files`
    do
      git --no-pager diff --binary ${START}..${END} $file > ~/temp/git-diff
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]
      then
#      Diff usually fail if the file got deleted 
        echo Skipping the merge: git diff command failed for $file >> ~/temp/error.log
        echo Skipping the merge: git diff command failed for $file
        echo "STATUS: FAILED $file" >>  /tmp/status
        echo "STATUS: FAILED $file"
    # skip the merge for this file and continue the merge for others
        rm -f ~/temp/git-diff
        continue
      fi

      git apply  --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace  --3way --allow-binary-replacement ~/temp/git-diff

      if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
#  apply failed, but it will fall back to 3-way merge, you can ignore this failure
         echo "git apply command filed for $file"
       fi
       echo
       STATUS=`git status -s $file`


       if [ ! "$STATUS" ]
       then
#   status is null if the merged diffs are already present in the target file
         echo "STATUS:NOT_MERGED $file"
         echo "STATUS: NOT_MERGED $file$"  >>  /tmp/status
       else
#     3 way merge is successful
         echo STATUS: $STATUS
         echo "STATUS: $STATUS"  >>  /tmp/status
       fi
    done

    echo GIT merge failed for below listed files

    cat ~/temp/error.log

    echo "Git merge status per file is available in /tmp/status"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've got only couple of commits and want to cherry-pick, you can simply do

```
git cherry-pick <commit> -n
```

on those commits and then make them into a new commit.

**-n** doesn't automatically create a commit rather just stages the changes hence you can continue to cherry-pick or make changes to the files in that commit.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to merge with strategy ours to the commit before the range and then a 'normal' merge with the last commit of that range (or branch when it is the last one). So suppose only 2345 and 3456 commits of master to be merged into feature branch:

```
master:
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

in feature branch:

```
git merge -s ours 4567
git merge 2345
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge can get difficult sometimes and it is easy to just create a patch and apply the changes manually.

- Create a patch file from **start_commit** to **end_commit**.

  `git diff <start_commit> <end_commit> > patch.diff`
- Checkout your branch and manually apply changes from the patch.