# git format patch limit?

Tags: git

I am trying to cherry pick some commits in my repo but it keeps on failing.
(I tried this tutorial on SO: "[What is the best way to git patch a subrange of a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509859/what-is-the-best-way-to-git-patch-a-subrange-of-a-branch)")

So I did a workaround:

- just do a `git format-patch` of the commits
- and just delete the extra files.

Really dirty stuff, but a bit easier to do.
So I do a

```
git format-patch -66
```

(the commit I was looking for was 66 commits away)

**Problem with this is it keeps stopping at 047**.
What gives? **Is there a limit to the patches I can generate?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-<n>` option of **[`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html)** is a bit tricky, as [this thread illustrates](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/154142), from git contributor (for gitweb) and SO user [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski):

> It looks like there is a conceptual bug in how git-format-patch works, namely that '`-<n>`' is passed to `rev-list` / `log` generating machinery, **and it limits number of *commits* to consider**;
>
> **if some of those commits are merge commits, which cannot be represented as patches, the number of patches it generates is less than specified `<n>`** (as you can see in 
>   the example I have provided, where `<n>` == 3, and git-format-patch generated 2 patches, not 3).
>
> In extreme case (like '`pu`') it can generate no patch.

(`pu` being here the [public branch of the git-scm repo](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/pu).)

In the OP's case, as he points out in the comment, it could mean 19 commits that are merge patches.

---

Jakub goes on proposing the following solution:

> Update `git-format-patch` documentation to say 'commits' instead of 'patches',
>   and perhaps also be loud about commits we are skipping, so that my example would look e.g. like this:

```
 $ git format-patch -3
 0001-gitweb-Prepare-for-splitting-gitweb.txt
 0002-gitweb-Create-Gitweb-Git-module.txt
 Skipping merge commit: Merge branch 'maint'
```

, to which [Ramkumar Ramachandra proposes last August (2010) to write a patch](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/154145).

You can see that patch simmering in this [September 2010 what's cooking in git.git](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/What-s-cooking-in-git-git-Sep-2010-01-Wed-1-td5488565.html)

> [New Topics]
>
> `rr/format-patch-count-without-merges` (2010-08-28) 2 commits
>    - `format-patch`: Don't go over merge commits
>    - `t4014-format-patch`: Call test_tick before committing

and is still in the latest [what's cooking (Sept. 27th)](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/What-s-cooking-in-git-git-Sep-2010-05-Wed-15-td5536326.html#a5573600) in the `[Cooking]` section, with the following annotation:

> Comments from potential users?

Comment: ohhh so that means i have like 19 commits that are merge patches. lemme try that